# Searching a shorter way to display time in digital format?

Tags: c#, datetime, time

Can this snippet been shorten, so that it still shows the current time
Like this: 08:24:09?
*and not like this 8:24.9*

My current Code:

```
this.lblClock = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
this.lblClock.Text = "00:00:00";
```

Clock ticks:

```
    private void _Clock_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime CurrTime = DateTime.Now;

        if (CurrTime.Hour > 9 && CurrTime.Minute > 9 && CurrTime.Second > 9)
            lblClock.Text = ("" + CurrTime.Hour + ":" + CurrTime.Minute + ":" + CurrTime.Second);
        if (CurrTime.Hour < 10 && CurrTime.Minute > 9 && CurrTime.Second > 9)
            lblClock.Text = ("0" + CurrTime.Hour + ":" + CurrTime.Minute + ":" + CurrTime.Second);
        if (CurrTime.Hour > 9 && CurrTime.Minute > 9 && CurrTime.Second < 10)
            lblClock.Text = ("" + CurrTime.Hour + ":" + CurrTime.Minute + ":" + "0" + CurrTime.Second);
        if (CurrTime.Hour < 10 && CurrTime.Minute > 9 && CurrTime.Second < 10)
            lblClock.Text = ("0" + CurrTime.Hour + ":" + CurrTime.Minute + ":" + "0" + CurrTime.Second);
        if (CurrTime.Hour > 9 && CurrTime.Minute < 10 && CurrTime.Second > 9)
            lblClock.Text = ("" + CurrTime.Hour + ":" + "0" + CurrTime.Minute + ":" + CurrTime.Second);
        if (CurrTime.Hour < 10 && CurrTime.Minute < 10 && CurrTime.Second > 9)
            lblClock.Text = ("0" + CurrTime.Hour + ":" + "0" + CurrTime.Minute + ":" + CurrTime.Second);
        if (CurrTime.Hour > 9 && CurrTime.Minute < 10 && CurrTime.Second < 10)
            lblClock.Text = ("" + CurrTime.Hour + ":" + "0" + CurrTime.Minute + ":" + "0" + CurrTime.Second);
        if (CurrTime.Hour < 10 && CurrTime.Minute < 10 && CurrTime.Second < 10)
            lblClock.Text = ("0" + CurrTime.Hour + ":" + "0" + CurrTime.Minute + ":" + "0" + CurrTime.Second);
    }
```

Can you shorten that snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use DateTime Format `"HH:mm:ss"` to show time in label.

```
lblClock.Text = CurrTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

If you want to show AM/PM then you can do:

```
lblClock.Text = CurrTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
```

Comment: Simple, that's what im looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MSDN page on [DateTime.ToString(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx)

You can do all kind of formats!! ... including `"HH:mm:ss"`, which is what you're after.